# Super Slow boot in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, nvidia, lenovo

I have currently installed ubuntu 18.04.02 it turns out that it boots up too slow.I don't even have windows in dual boot with Ubuntu. My laptop specifications are

```
8th Gen Intel Core i5-8250U
NVIDIA GEFORCE MX150 (2G GDDR5) graphics
1 TB HDD
ram-8 GB
```

When I ran

```
systemd-analyze time
```

I got this results

```
Startup finished in 3.961s (firmware) + 4.207s (loader) + 3.699s (kernel) + 32.893s (userspace) = 44.762s
graphical.target reached after 32.876s in userspace
```

when I ran

```
 systemd-analyze blame
```

I got

```
9.471s apparmor.service
          8.423s dev-sda2.device
          7.925s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
          7.479s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          6.352s snapd.service
          5.076s bolt.service
          4.843s gpu-manager.service
          4.499s dev-loop4.device
          3.933s NetworkManager.service
          3.775s dev-loop9.device
          3.764s networkd-dispatcher.service
          3.321s dev-loop0.device
          3.283s dev-loop6.device
          3.124s dev-loop8.device
          3.034s ModemManager.service
          2.950s dev-loop7.device
          2.888s dev-loop5.device
          2.836s systemd-journal-flush.service
          2.762s dev-loop1.device
          2.656s dev-loop3.device
          2.615s dev-loop2.device
          2.611s udisks2.service
          2.536s thermald.service
          1.904s systemd-udevd.service
          1.725s accounts-daemon.service
          1.627s wpa_supplicant.service
          1.463s console-setup.service
          1.302s bluetooth.service
          1.247s systemd-timesyncd.service
          1.247s systemd-resolved.service
          1.222s grub-common.service
          1.179s plymouth-read-write.service
           993ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
           968ms dns-clean.service
           920ms systemd-sysctl.service
           817ms apport.service
           788ms fwupd.service
           785ms networking.service
           683ms pppd-dns.service
           669ms systemd-modules-load.service
           669ms nvidia-persistenced.service
           652ms systemd-logind.service
           636ms keyboard-setup.service
           591ms rsyslog.service
           550ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5338\x2d4FE1.service
           548ms snap-core-6350.mount
           509ms polkit.service
           471ms snap-vlc-1049.mount
           449ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-139.mount
           398ms systemd-rfkill.service
           360ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0d52a478\x2d7fc6\x2d4ec3\x2da7
           355ms avahi-daemon.service
           318ms setvtrgb.service
           315ms upower.service
           295ms snap-overleaf-2.mount
           279ms packagekit.service
           256ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-260.mount
           255ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-c1c89474\x2d700e\x2d4066\x2d9650\x2d6bb12c1
           251ms user@121.service
           247ms systemd-random-seed.service
           245ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-818.mount
           243ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-57.mount
           230ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-74.mount
           224ms snap-spotify-36.mount
           208ms home.mount
           206ms gdm.service
           147ms systemd-remount-fs.service
           144ms systemd-journald.service
           140ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           122ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
           101ms snapd.socket
            84ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-45.mount
            72ms speech-dispatcher.service
            72ms kerneloops.service
            70ms user@1000.service
            67ms systemd-user-sessions.service
            65ms systemd-update-utmp.service
            58ms boot-efi.mount
            53ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
            53ms kmod-static-nodes.service
            50ms ufw.service
            48ms colord.service
            45ms alsa-restore.service
            44ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
            41ms snapd.seeded.service
            39ms rtkit-daemon.service
            18ms dev-hugepages.mount
            14ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             7ms ureadahead-stop.service
             3ms dev-mqueue.mount
             2ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
             1ms sys-kernel-config.mount
             1ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
```

when I ran

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain
```

I got

```
graphical.target @32.876s
└─multi-user.target @32.876s
  └─kerneloops.service @32.803s +72ms
    └─network-online.target @32.775s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @25.295s +7.479s
        └─NetworkManager.service @21.361s +3.933s
          └─dbus.service @20.698s
            └─basic.target @20.683s
              └─sockets.target @20.683s
                └─snapd.socket @20.581s +101ms
                  └─sysinit.target @20.580s
                    └─apparmor.service @11.079s +9.471s
                      └─local-fs.target @11.077s
                        └─run-user-121.mount @27.731s
                          └─swap.target @10.422s
                            └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-c1c89474\x2d700e\x2d4066\x2d96
                              └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-c1c89474\x2d700e\x2d4066\x2d
```

can any body help me to boot it  faster.

Comment: Next step is to look at `systemctl status apparmor.service` and `journalctl -u apparmor.service` to try to understand why it's taking almost 10s to start... You can also try to do the same for some of the other services in the critical chain (but it looks like apparmor should be the easiest one and the one with most potential for improvement.)

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167070/systemd-tmpfiles-setup-service-takes-too-long-1hr-on-boot